# SQL Server replace function bug?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Am I missing something in the the following statement?

```
select replace('xAxAxAx', 'xAx', 'xBx')
```

Because it results in:

```
xBxAxBx
```

Is this known bug or I have missed something basic here?

Microsoft says that `replace` function:

> Replaces all occurrences of a specified string value with another
>   string value.

Isn't second `xAx` an occurrence here?

Comment: What would you want the result to be?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I know that I can get desired result with `replace('xAxAxAx', 'A', 'B')`, but I was expecting replace behaving with `replace('xAxAxAx', 'xAx', 'xBx')` result in `xBxBxBx`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's jut matter of definition what is an occurrence and how do you deal with overlapping instances. That's exactly how I would expect it to work, since handling the data one occurrence at the time means that 'xAxAxAx' is xAx + A + xAx -- and whatever is the result of the first replaced isn't being considered as a new occurrence, therefore those 2 get replaced.

Similarly the result of replace ('xx', 'x', 'xx') is xxxx, not xxxxxxxxxx....

Answer (score 3):

No, the second `xAx` is not an occurance. An occurance can not overlap another occurance, so there are only two occurances of `xAx` in the string:

```
'xAx' + 'A' + 'xAx'
```

Consider if you did a replacement like this, which makes it a bit clearer:

```
replace('xAxAxAx', 'xAx', '-B-')
```

If the second `xAx` would count as an occurance, after replacing the first occurance, would the string be `-B-xAxAx`? Would the `x` that is shared between the first `xAx` and the second be duplicated so that it could be replaced in both occurances? Still, that would make the result `-B--B--B-` rather than `-B-B-B-`.